# IPv6 Address filtering behaving unusually

Tags: node.js, ipv6, cidr

I am using node js and in particular this package [cidr-matcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cidr-matcher) in combination with a rate limiter in order to exclude certain IPs from being rate limited.

Specifically the one CIDR expression for exclusion is:

```
::ffff:25.0.0.0/112
```

A rough sketch of the code for deciding whether to exclude is:

```js
  import Matcher from "cidr-matcher";
  ...

  public shouldRateLimitIp(ipAddress: IpAddress): boolean {
    const excludedIpsMatcher = new Matcher(["::ffff:25.0.0.0/112"]);
    return !excludedIpsMatcher.contains(ipAddress);
  }
```

However, I see that IP addresses of say `::ffff:25.0.31.1` are correctly excluded where as `::ffff:25.0.1.1` never is.

In my mind `::ffff:25.0.1.1` should be excluded by the CIDR above and is in unit tests.

And I notice that in production,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very sorry folks, it I was also posting to the rate limiter from a second environment which meant that this was a false positive. Mods welcome to delete, else I will soon enough.